# Pandas Using a Datetime column in a Dataframe to have the nearest match comparing with multiple Datetime columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge, pandas-groupby

Using a Datetime column in a Dataframe to have the nearest match comparing with multiple Datetime columns

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime_1' : ['2/4/2015 2:00:00','3/5/2015 3:00:00','4/3/2015 4:00:00'],
                    'Datetime_2' : ['2/3/2015 2:00:00','3/3/2015 3:00:00','4/3/2015 4:10:00'],
                    'Datetime_3' : ['2/4/2015 2:00:10','3/5/2015 3:20:00','4/3/2015 4:10:10']})
```

---

```
    Datetime_1          Datetime_2          Datetime_3         Amount
0   2/4/2015 2:00:00    2/3/2015 2:00:00    2/4/2015 2:00:10    100
1   3/5/2015 3:00:00    3/3/2015 3:00:00    3/5/2015 3:20:00    700
2   4/3/2015 4:00:00    4/3/2015 4:10:00    4/3/2015 4:10:10    1000
```

---

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime_1' : ['2/4/2015 2:00:05','3/5/2015 3:11:00','4/3/2015 4:00:01']})
```

---

```
       Datetime_1       Values
0   2/4/2015 2:00:05    10
1   3/5/2015 3:11:00    70
2   4/3/2015 4:10:01    100
```

**Expected output**

```
 Datetime_1              Nearest_Match_df1     Values   Amount    MatchColumn 
 2/4/2015 2:00:05        2/4/2015 2:00:00      10       100       Datetime_1
 3/5/2015 3:11:00        3/5/2015 3:20:00      70       700       Datetime_3
 4/3/2015 4:10:01        4/3/2015 4:10:00      100      1000      Datetime_2
```

Comment: Do you want to compare the time in the two dataframes by row-by-row, or all time in df2 compare to all time in df1

Comment: @QuangHoang row-by-row

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) after modifying `df1` to get all the dates in a single column. To do so, you `set_index` the column Amount then `stack` the dataframe, then `reset_index`, `rename` the column to match the expected output and duplicates the column with the dates to perform the merge.

```
df_res = pd.merge_asof( df2,
                        df1.set_index('Amount').stack().reset_index(name='Nearest_Match_df1')
                           .rename(columns={'level_1': 'MatchColumn'})
                           .assign(Datetime_1=lambda x: x.Nearest_Match_df1)
                           .sort_values(by=['Datetime_1']),
                        on = ['Datetime_1'], direction='nearest')

print (df_res)
           Datetime_1  values  Amount MatchColumn   Nearest_Match_df1
0 2015-02-04 02:00:05      10     100  Datetime_1 2015-02-04 02:00:00
1 2015-03-05 03:11:00      70     700  Datetime_3 2015-03-05 03:20:00
2 2015-04-03 04:00:01     100    1000  Datetime_1 2015-04-03 04:00:00
```

Note: all the columns must be of `Datetime` type

Comment: is this 'on = ['Datetime_1']' referring to the df1 or df2 or bioth.  what if the Date column for df1 is Datetime, how will it work?

Comment: @heykay So it is because the name of the date column in `df2` is `Datetime_1` that I use this name in the `assign` when modifying the shape of `df1` to be able to perform the merge on this column, does it make sense ?

Comment: Another scenario, whats if the Value and Amount in both df's are the same like unique identifier. how will that work?

Comment: @heykay you mean you want to merge first on the same value in the columns Amount and Value?